# url request with token swift

Tags: swift, url

I'm trying to connect to a url starting from a main path and then adding the token that identifies the user's identity.
however, despite downloading the token and pointing to the correct url, I see the login page and not the home already logged in.

in debug if I take the same url with token already composed and the shianto as url directs me to the home

```
    #if DEBUG
internal var basePath  = "https://backoffice-ludde5846.vercel.app/purchase?token="
#else
internal var basePath  = "https://app/purchase?token="
#endif
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let token = AppDelegate.sharedInstance().getToken() else { return  }
    
    guard let url = URL(string: basePath + token) else {
        return
    }
    
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webview?.load(request)
}
```

Comment: Is `getToken()` synchronous or asynchronous?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear `webview`'s cookies/cache before the `load()` function.